# javascript add and remove multiple value from a list in and from specific index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a code like:

```
var data = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "fish", "gorilla"]
var index = [1, 3] // ball and dog
var to = 5 // fish

for(var i in index){
  console.log(index[i])
  var local_data = data
  data.splice(to, 0, data.splice(index[i]), 1)
}

console.log(data)
console.log(index)
```

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1h8dra6s/)**

Here `var index = [1,3]` is the index value of the data to be set.

What I want here is, to set the value of `index` i. e `ball` and `dog` after  `fish` and the rest remains on the order.

After inserted I want the `index` value to be changed according to the new position of the `ball` and `dog` i. e `[4, 5]`

**Updata**

In the end I want the result like:
`console.log(data)` should give

```
["apple", "cat", "elephant", "fish", "ball", "dog", "gorilla"]
```

and `console.log(index)` should give:

```
[4, 5] // new value of ball and dog
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your desired end result? Perhaps with the state of the variables you want at the end of the code?

Comment: @user01 check the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in this way.

```js
var data = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "fish", "gorilla"]
var index = [4, 5]; 
var to = 2  ;

var arrTemp = [];

data.forEach(function(val,key){

  if(index.indexOf(key)!=-1){

    data.splice((to+1),0,data[key]);
    to++;
    delete data[key];

  }
})
data = data.filter(function(val){ return val != undefined }); 

console.log(data)


UPDATE : 

var data = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "fish", "gorilla"]
var index = [ 2,3];
var to = 5 ;
var arrTemp = [];

data.forEach(function(val,key){

  if(index.indexOf(key)!=-1){    
    arrTemp.push(data[key]);
    delete data[key];

  }
})

to=to+1;
for(var pos=0;pos<index.length;pos++){
   data.splice(to++,0,arrTemp[pos])
}
data = data.filter(function(val){ return val != undefined });
```

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1h8dra6s/1/)**

Comment: Few issues.. if I put `index = [2, 3]` its giving me `null` in `2` index.. and the value of `index` is not updated after splice

Comment: It gives correct value if I put something like `[2, 4]` but error on `[2, 3]`

Comment: thank you so much.. and how to update the index with new value ??

Comment: If you removed n item them subtract n from each index arr element

Comment: some errors over here like if `index = [4,5]` and `to = 2` its giving weired error.. It is repeating `4th` value..

Comment: can you figure out how to do with `index = [4, 5]` and `to = 2`

Comment: you doing with same array?

Comment: iteration can be anywhere.. like value of `index` and `to` might change..

Answer (score 1):

Tricky problem but was fun solving it.

This is my solution, probably not the most efficient one but hey it got the work done.

```
var data = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "fish", "gorilla"];
var output = [];
var index = [1, 3]; // ball and dog
var to = 5; // fish

var extractValues = [];
index.forEach(function(i){
  extractValues.push(data[i]);
});

var valueToPutAfter = data[to];

// Put the value first
data.forEach(function(element) {
  if (element === valueToPutAfter) { // found element to push after
    output.push(element);
    extractValues.forEach(function(value){
      output.push(value);
    });
  }
  else {
    output.push(element);
  }

});


// Mark the position that needs to be deleted as null
var prevDelIndex = 0;
index.forEach(function(i){
  output[i] = null;
});

// delete the elements
output.forEach(function(element, index) {
  if (element == null) {
      output.splice(index, 1);
  }
});

console.log(output);
console.log(output.indexOf("ball"));
console.log(output.indexOf("dog"));
```

I have decompose your problem into a few small ones and tackle them in a systematic manner.

My approach is first loop through the data array and push all the elements including the new ones. Then go through the list again and mark those elements found in position, variable index array" as null and remove them.

**Algorithm walkthrough:**

1. I first workout what needs to be extracted from the array (data).
2. Similarly for the element that needs to be put after.
3. I loop through the initial array to find that element mentioned in
   point (2), then start putting whatever needs to come after behind
   it.
4. Now you will have an array which consists of the original value plus
   the new items.
5. Using the garbage collection concept, I go through the new array and
   mark the "to-be-deleted" element as null. This is so that I know
   which element to delete with splice later.
6. Once again, I loop through the new array looking for the flagged
   element (null) and remove them.

Now you will left with what you wanted.

**Output:**

> [ 'apple', 'cat', 'elephant', 'fish', 'ball', 'dog', 'gorilla' ]
>
> indexOf 'ball' = 4
>
> indexOf 'dog' = 5

Answer (score 1):

This works now in situ and uses some offset indicators like `left` for the extracting value and `right` for inserting the value.

After finishing, the indices are calculated based on the `left` offset.

> ```
> Example for from = [1, 3, 6], to = 5
>
>            from              from               to               from      offset
>     0        1        2        3        4        5        6        7     left right
> -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- ----- ----- 
>   apple   [ball]     cat     [dog]  elephant  (fish)   gorilla [banana]   0     0
>   apple     cat     [dog]  elephant  (fish)   [ball]   gorilla [banana]  -1     0
>   apple     cat   elephant  (fish)   [ball]    [dog]   gorilla [banana]  -2     0
>   apple     cat   elephant  (fish)   [ball]    [dog]  [banana]  gorilla  -2     1
> ```

```js
function juggle(data, from, to) {
    var left = 0,
        right = 0;

    from.forEach(function (a) {
        if (a + left < to) {
            data.splice(to, 0, data.splice(a + left, 1)[0]);
            left--;
        } else {
            right++;
            data.splice(to + right, 0, data.splice(a, 1)[0]);
        }
    });
    from.forEach(function (_, i, a) { a[i] = to + left + i + 1; });
}

var data = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "fish", "gorilla", "banana"],
    index = [1, 3, 7], // ball dog banana
    to = 5;            // fish
   
juggle(data, index, to);
console.log(data);
console.log(index);

data = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "fish", "gorilla", "banana"];
index = [4, 5];        // elephant fish
to = 2;                // cat

juggle(data, index, to);
console.log(data);
console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, nice problem, really enjoyed hacking my way through this. I took a function approach since that's not done yet:

```
var data = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "fish", "gorilla"]
var index = [2, 3] // ball and dog
var to = 5 // fish

var moveItemsToPosition = function (data, indices, to) {
  var movingItems = [];
  var after = data[to + 1];

  for (var i = 0 ; i < indices.length; i++) {
    // takes out the items that will be moved form the original array
    movingItems.push(data[indices[i] - i]);
    data.splice(indices[i] - i, 1);
  }

  // finds the new position of the item to move next to
  var pos = data.indexOf(after);
  var data2 = data.slice(pos, data.length);
  // join the items that will be moved
  data = data.slice(0, pos).concat(movingItems);
  data = data.concat(data2);
  // update the indices
  for (var i = 0 ; i < indices.length; i++) {
    // get the new indices
    indices[i] = data.indexOf(movingItems[i]);
  }

  return [data, indices];
}

console.log(moveItemsToPosition(data, index, to));
```

It returns both the updated array and the new indices. You can remove this as necessary. Basically the algorithm first takes out the items needed to be moved and then finds the item next to which it needs to be moved and places it there (with the help of fancy JS).

Hope this helps!